# getting error while running karma unit test cases "unknown [ object object ] thrown"

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular-test

I am new to karma unit test and i am getting below error while running karma unit test cases using angular ionic.

```
unknown [ object object ] thrown.
```

There is no more details other-than this message. I am not clear due to what it causing this issue. I have attached screenshot below.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGMZQ.png)

Comment: share screenshot of what the test is doing

Answer (score 0):

try to run test cases as

```
ng test --browsers=Chrome
```

this will open the chrome browser and then run test cases
In developer tools navigate to console tab and there you can check the details of the error

Comment: After running ng test --browsers=Chrome also getting same error

Comment: If there is same error on console tab then there must be file name and line number attached with that error message on console, this will guide you to the source of error

Comment: Also here you can put breakpoints in your code while running tests from which you can get details of the error